# ActiveRecord default timezone fails to read back from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, timezone, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to get all my models to write timestamps using EST timezone in a DB2 database that's also configured to EST.

I already configured my `application.rb` configuration with the following:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

When I create a new record and save to the database the timestamps look fine:

```
=> #<TZTestModel id: 3500, added_ts: nil, ...>
irb(main):002:0> rec.added_ts = Time.zone.now
=> Fri, 06 Nov 2015 19:03:42 EST -05:00
irb(main):003:0> rec.added_ts
=> Fri, 06 Nov 2015 19:03:42 EST -05:00
irb(main):004:0> rec.save
SQL (91.0ms)  INSERT INTO TZTESTMODEL(id, added_ts, ...) VALUES (3500, '2015-11-06 19:06:55.237000', ...)
=> true
```

I query the database and I can see the record inserted with the correct timestamp. But then, when I try to read the record back through ActiveRecord, the timestamp field is nil:

```
irb(main):008:0> TZTestModel.first
=> #<TZTestModel id: 3500, added_ts: nil, ...>
```

This only happens if I set the default timezone in `application.rb`. If I don't add the configuration, then AR defaults to UTC and can write and read the timestamp fields with no issues at all.

Please, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. The problem is that `config.active_record.default_timezone` accepts only two values/symbols while running under RoR: `:utc` or `:local`.
I set the value to `:local` and it picks up the time zone perfectly.
The full configuration in `application.rb` is now:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

When the timestamp is added to an object of the model, the model still stores the value in UTC, but it automatically converts to EST before writing to the database and on read (e.g. before outputting as string).

I also have one piece of my application that's a daemon written in Ruby (not RoR). In this daemon I set the AR default timestamp to EST directly instead of :local, and I also set the ENV['TZ'] value to 'EST', to make sure any date/time operations done outside AR also use the correct timezone, like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
ENV['TZ'] = 'EST'
```

This makes the timezones consistent across both sides of my application (the RoR app and the Ruby daemon).